# Qt - Mapping two tables on the widgets using QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: qt, sqlite, qtsql

There are two tables in SQLite. For a simple example, person and address.
How to map data of the current man from both tables to form widgets? How should we synchronize the current index of the two tables, if we use two `QDataWidgetMapper`'s?

Is there another approach to display related data on the form, including insertion?

I would be very grateful for your help and examples.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to [join two SQL tables](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) (say `person` and `address`). If this is the case, you would need a [`QSqlQueryModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#details).

Note that `QDataWidgetMapper` is used for sharing a single model among multiple widgets. However in this case, it seems you want to show data from two tables in one widget.

```
 QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
 model->setQuery("SELECT name, city FROM person INNER JOIN address ON persion.id=address.id");
 model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
 model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("City"));
```

Now, you can use this 2D model wherever you need. Also you can use a `QDataWidgetMapper` with this model in order to share its data with multiple widgets.